Можно ли использовать DLL библиотеку написанную на Delphi Rio в приложение написанном на Delphi 7?
У меня есть приложение (exe) написанное на Delphi 7. С этим приложением уже связаны некоторые библиотеки (dll) так же написанные на Delphi 7. Можно ли написать библиотеку на Delphi Rio и связать её с приложением на Delphi 7?

Да, конечно. В общем случае, в отличии от BPL, DLL библиотеки "стандартные" и им все равно на каком языке они были написаны (а уж тем более версии компилятора).
Затруднения могут возникнуть с передачей строк (Ansi / Wide / Unicode), но это не критично.
Более сложные объекты (например, исключения) передавать все равно не рекомендуется (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120545):

"The whole idea about DLL's is that they are language independent"
"nothing language specific should cross a dll boundary"

Плюс http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html

Delphi 7 была (и будет) 32-разрядной. Dll тоже ведь в этом случае нужно компилировать в 32 бита?

@VladChapl говорят что да - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396897.
